# How to create trigger in oracle with IF-else statement, and output should be a description

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

Create a trigger TR_SIGHTING_DESC that will automatically populate the sighting
description column according to the following template.
‘A bird of the species BIRD-NAME was spotted in the X-Y part of the
observation area’

```
 **CREATE TABLE birds(
bird_id NUMBER,
bird_name VARCHAR2(50)
);

CREATE TABLE sightings(
sighting_id NUMBER,
spotter_id NUMBER,
bird_id NUMBER,
latitude NUMBER,
longitude NUMBER,
sighting_date DATE,
description VARCHAR2(255)
);**

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "TR_SIGNTING_DESC"
BEFORE INSERT ON sightings
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    X VARCHAR(5)
    Y VARCHAR(7)
    NAME VARCHAR2(50)
BEGIN
    IF (:NEW.latitude >-28.1) THEN
    SET X:='north';
    ELSE
    SET X:='south';
    END IF;
    IF (:NEW.longgitude>151.25) THEN
    SET Y:='eastern';
    ELSE
    SET Y:='western';
    END IF;
    SELECT bird_name INTO NAME FROM birds WHERE bird_id= :NEW.bird_id
    :NEW.description := CONCAT('A bird of the species', NAME, ' was spotted     in the ',X,'-',Y,' part of the observation area')   

END;
/
```

Comment: And the question is?  I'm guessing that you are getting an error but it's helpful to provide the error stack.  Your variable declarations are missing semicolon which would cause an error.  But I don't know if that is a transcription error.  `concat` also only accepts two arguments.  You could have a bunch of nested concat calls or you could build the string using the `||` operator.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just start to learn SQL,  the || operator  kick ass!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should delete **set** from trigger text; And forget some **";"**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "TR_SIGNTING_DESC"
BEFORE INSERT ON sightings
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    X VARCHAR2(5);
    Y VARCHAR2(7);
    NAME VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
    IF (:NEW.latitude >-28.1) THEN
      X :='north';
    ELSE
      X :='south';
    END IF;
    IF (:NEW.longgitude>151.25) THEN
      Y:='eastern';
    ELSE
      Y:='western';
    END IF;
    SELECT bird_name 
      INTO NAME 
      FROM birds 
     WHERE bird_id= :NEW.bird_id;

    :NEW.description := 'A bird of the species' || NAME || ' was spotted     in the ' || X || '-' || Y || ' part of the observation area';

    END;
/
```

Comment: If I rigth could you please mark question as answerd